# How to find html/php file via Dev Tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, filezilla

I have to find a specific file in a ftp server. 
Let say I want to edit a `<h1>` tag but I can't find where does he come from.

**Is there a way to show the name of the file where the specific element select come from?**

Like it does for css file : 
[image: css exemple]

**Plus is there a way a way to find the whole path?**

Precision : the content is added by smarty (for the most part) and the url has nothing to do with the real path).

Comment: Unless you have frames involved, the file is always going to be the one at the end of the URL listed in the address bar of the browser. (Unless the content was added by JavaScript, of course).

Comment: Content added by smarty the url has nothing to do with the path :/

Comment: The client has no way to tell where the *server* gets it's data from in order to generate the response to the request for a URL.

Comment: @Quentin so it only work for css ? (Since he get the precise name of each style sheet).

Comment: It tells you what the URL of the CSS is, not the filename. There's just not a lot of point in doing that for HTML since (a) there's usually just the URL in the address bar and (b) HTML is much more commonly modified with JS than CSS anyway

Comment: @Quentin So there is no way to find where it come from else check every file in my ftp?

Comment: Normally you'd check the local checkout of your project from version control rather then attacking the live code directly.

Comment: I'd like that to be that way but I'm maintaining  an online site I haven't coded which is an hell of a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to approach this would be to search for the tag on all your files using your IDE.

I use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com), which is designed for code search.

The reason why devtools can't do what you're asking is because it is not possible for chrome to know about all the files in your project. There are too many variables, tags can be created with javascript, php server side, html files and so on.

Comment: @Baldráni I think sublime is great, I am just used to ack. Does that answer your question?